# Find top 5 field values in each record. Return value and column heading. MS Access

Tags: ms-access

Hello and thanks in advance for any help.

I wrote a small program in Access that imports text files and places them into tables.  The table is laid out with about 20 fields and each field represents a different category that contains a number (hours) for different reasons, for each record.  I have been unable to find anything that will get me started in the right direction and need help.

What I want to do is search each record and find the highest five numbers for each record and then return each value with the associated heading for that field.

For example

```
             PGM     ASD     HFR     STE     NHU
```

Client A    _____365.4__ 255___254.6___180.1___26

Once I figure out how to query this info from the other 20 columns, my goal is to build a form that have this query attached to a button that returns these values.  I can either set it up to search each record or search all records and find the the top five values for all clients.

Again, thanks for any help.  I am not hoping that someone will build me a solution, just get me a reference or some material to get me heading in a direction.

Answer (score 1):

In Access, this will require a custom function that compares values of fields. Common requirement is to find the top 1 value from a record. Has been discussed many times in many sites. Google. Finding top 5 does add complication. If data structure were normalized, a TOP N nested query could probably provide desired output.

A workaround for the current structure could be to build a UNION query that rearranges your data to normalized structure (data is vertical instead of horizontal). Then use that query like a table as the source for TOP N nested query. Is there only 1 record for each client? UNION example:

```
SELECT Client, PGM AS Hrs, "PGM" AS Source FROM tablename
UNION SELECT Client, ASD, "ASD" FROM tablename
UNION SELECT Client, HFR, "HFR" FROM tablename
UNION SELECT Client, STE, "STE" FROM tablename
UNION SELECT Client, NHU, "NHU" FROM tablename
continue for 15 other fields;
```

Must type or copy/paste in SQLView of query builder. Limit of 50 SELECT lines.

For example of TOP N review http://allenbrowne.com/subquery-01.html#TopN. Unfortunately, this type of nested query can be slow performer. And basing it off a UNION instead of natural table can be even slower.

Comment: Yes, there is only record each.  The table will never get any bigger and it is only about 50-60 records.   Each record is basically a location, and each column is a different category of time used.  All data in the table is hours.  I thought re-arranging the locations to fields and the categories as records.  Not sure if the is better or easier to work with......?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: That arrangement would not be any easier to work with. The TOP N nested query approach would mean a query for each location field. I don't think you want 50-60 queries.

Comment: To avoid the 50-60 queries would still need UNION to rearrange to normalized structure and then do the same TOP N nested query.

Comment: I have an idea of the logic that I would use for the loops, just not sure how or if I can code it in the SQL editor in access.  I was thinking that I can create a loop to go through each record individually, and a nested loops within each other that not only return the values, but the column heading.  I will post a solution once I create it and would appreciate any help to get me towards that goal.

Comment: June7 - I went ahead with your recommendation and used the union.  The issue is that there are a total of 55 fields and I need all of them because they contain relevant data.  SQL will not query over 50 Unions and throws and error saying it is too complex.  This method would have been perfect because it easily sorted the data by value and I could pull the top 5 values in my form.  Do you know if I can work around the limit of 50 by nesting Unions or splitting the tables into two separate queries joined by a crosstab query?  The only issue with that is I will need to make 165 queries.

Comment: I have never tried to UNION two UNION queries. Try it and see what happens.

Comment: Not sure if I could.  Thought you may know.  I'll give it a shot.