# Transpose a table in Access using VB code

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a table that is populated with data from a delimited text file.  The data comes from another system and I cannot modify how it is generated into the text file I am importing.  Once the data is imported into access, it is not in a normalized fashion.  The first two columns of data are date ranges, the third is a location code, the remaining 54 columns hold specific data for each location.  I need to find the top five values for each record so I can put them into a report.

I had posed this question in another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44075174/find-top-5-field-values-in-each-record-return-value-and-column-heading-ms-acce), but was unable to find a solution.  In that thread, someone recommended that I used a union query.  It appeared that it was going to work perfectly, but you can only use 50 unions in access and I have to many fields.

Now I am trying to use VB code in access to transpose the table.  I am working with the following code that I retrieved from this [page](http://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/dataanalysis/normalization/transpose.html).  It is throwing an error on execution.  I cannot figure out what the issue is.  I know it is a syntax error or creating the object, but I have tried everything I can think of and cannot get it to work.  Also, The column headers would contain string info so I was going to change the variable to a variant instead of an integer?  Any help with this code, or suggestions regarding how to get what I want from the table would be appreciated.

Picture of actual [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BP6AY.png).

I am getting a error -> 'Run-time error '3265':  Item not found in this collection.

```
Private Sub Command78_Click()


  Const cstrInputTable = "Base Period OT"
  Const cstrOutputTable As String = "Normalized Base Period OT"

  Dim dbs As DAO.Database
  Dim rstInput As DAO.Recordset
  Dim rstOutput As DAO.Recordset
  Dim intYear As Integer

  Set dbs = CurrentDb
  Set rstInput = dbs.OpenRecordset(cstrInputTable)
  Set rstOutput = dbs.OpenRecordset(cstrOutputTable)

  If Not rstInput.EOF Then
    ' For each column in the Input table, create a record in the output   table
    For intYear = 1990 To 2011
      rstInput.MoveFirst
      rstOutput.AddNew
        rstOutput![Year] = intYear

        ' Go through every record in the Input table
        Do
          rstOutput(rstInput![Data Type]) = rstInput(CStr(intYear))
          rstInput.MoveNext
        Loop Until rstInput.EOF

      rstOutput.Update
    Next intYear
  End If
  rstInput.Close
  rstOutput.Close
  dbs.Close

  MsgBox "Data Successfully Transformed"
  DoCmd.OpenTable cstrOutputTable

End Sub
```

Comment: It's very hard to debug a picture.  Please paste your code into the question to save us having to retype it.

Comment: Also, *"It is throwing an error on execution."* -- please add the full error message to your question.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me.  Newbie here.  Post updated.

Comment: Not too sure I fully understand what you're trying to achieve here. Can you post a small sample of the data (or even an image)?

Comment: You also need to include your table structures.

Comment: I have included a picture above the run time error code.

Comment: When you say the top 5 values you mean from ALL columns per record except BEGIN DT, END DATE, CDE and LOCATION?

Comment: For each record in the current table (location) I want to find the top 5 values for each column in the current table and the column header (3 letter code).   By transposing the table I can auto sort the column by highest value and get the top 5 by query.

Answer (score 1):

Still not sure I have fully understood your inputs and outputs. I'll give it a try though and you let me know if I'm even close to what you're looking for.

You can create a *"Temp"* table with only 3 fields just for sorting purposes. You can then loop through your source table and add Location, Column header (3 letter code) and the value of each field to the *"Temp"* table.

You can then sort by value DESC and select the top 5.

```
Public Sub GetTopFive()
    On Error GoTo ErrProc

    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT Location, AMR, AXT, BRM, BMM, CSR, CTC " & _
                                     "FROM DataSource ORDER BY Location;", dbOpenSnapshot)

    If rs.EOF Then GoTo Leave
    With rs
        .MoveLast
        .MoveFirst
    End With

    Dim idx As Long
    For idx = 1 To rs.RecordCount
            AddToTempTable rs
           'Now the Temp table holds one Location, sorted by value
           'Selecting the top 5 records will give you what you're looking for
           'If that's the case, provide additional info on how to handle this 
           'as each location might have different field names.
        rs.MoveNext
    Next idx


Leave:
    On Error Resume Next
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub

ErrProc:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical
    Resume Leave
End Sub

'Add To Temp for sorting
Private Sub AddToTempTable(rs As DAO.Recordset)

    Dim fld As DAO.Field
    For Each fld In rs.Fields
        If fld.Name <> "Location" Then
            With CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qryAddToTemp")
                .Parameters("[prmLocation]").Value = rs!Location
                .Parameters("[prmFileldName]").Value = fld.Name
                .Parameters("[prmFieldValue]").Value = fld.Value
                .Execute dbFailOnError
            End With
        End If
    Next fld
End Sub
```

---

Import query

```
PARAMETERS [prmLocation] Text ( 255 ), [prmFileldName] Text ( 255 ), [prmFieldValue] IEEESingle;
INSERT INTO tbTemp ( Location, [Field Name], [Field Value] )
SELECT [prmLocation] AS Location, [prmFileldName] AS [Field Name], [prmFieldValue] AS [Field Value];
```

---

Temp Table

[image: Temp Table]

### Update:

```
Public Sub GetTopFive()
    On Error GoTo ErrProc

    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT Location, AMR, AXT, BRM, BMM, CSR, CTC " & _
                                     "FROM DataSource ORDER BY Location;", dbOpenSnapshot)

    If rs.EOF Then GoTo Leave
    With rs
        .MoveLast
        .MoveFirst
    End With

    Dim rsTemp As DAO.Recordset, fld As DAO.Field, idx As Long
    Set rsTemp = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tbTemp")

    With rsTemp
        For idx = 1 To rs.RecordCount
            For Each fld In rs.Fields
                If fld.Name <> "Location" Then
                    .AddNew
                    .Fields("YourCodeColumnName").Value = fld.Name
                    .Fields(rs!Location).Value = fld.Value
                    .Update
                End If
            Next fld
            rs.MoveNext
        Next idx
    End With

Leave:
    On Error Resume Next
    rsTemp.Close
    Set rsTemp = Nothing
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub

ErrProc:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical
    Resume Leave
End Sub
```

Comment: That is what I am trying to do except have each location across the top as fields, and have the three letter codes down the left as columns.  Then you could look at the AXT record, and scan across and see how much overtime hours were incurred for that code at each location.  Each location (Albany, Amherst, etc).  Yes, I would like to run the code to put it in a temp table so I can do individual queries on the temp table.

Comment: See update. I haven't been able to test it here at work but it should be fine. I'll test it properly when I get home.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you have provided there are 6 possibilities of where you are getting error 3265, and 4 of them have the same solution, once you understand how DAO Recordset objects work and reference fields in the "Table" they represent.

The error `Item not found in this collection`, given the code you have presented indicates that you are referencing a field name (column name) in the recordset that does not exist.  Or, that you are referencing a table name that does not exist in the database.

Since your code is dynamically determining field names, and you haven't provided the structure of the tables `Base Period OT` or `Normalized Base Period OT`, you will have to figure part of this out on your own.

Here are the 4 places where the error could be occurring for the Recordset objects and what you are looking for:

1. `rstOutput![Year] = intYear`, you are telling Access that you expect a column named "Year" to exist in your table `Normalized Base Period OT` and that you want to insert the current value of `intYear` into that column.  If "Year" is not a column name in that table, this would be the problem.
2. 3, & 4. `rstOutput(rstInput![Data Type]) = rstInput(CStr(intYear))`  In this single line of code, you have 3 possible locations for the error.

   a. `rstInput![Data Type]` Does the table `Base Period OT` contain a column named "Data Type"?  If not, this would be an error.  Here you are statically providing the name of the column that you expect to exist in the input table.

   b. `rstOutput(rstInput![Data Type])`  Assuming that `rstInput![Data Type]` is a valid column, the value in that column is now the name of the column you are expecting to exist in `Normalized Base Period OT`.  If that is not true, this would be an error.  Here, you are dynamically providing the name of the column that you expect to exist in the output table.

   c. `rstInput(CStr(intYear))` Does the table `Base Period OT` contain a column for the current value of `intYear` (i.e. does that table contain columns named 1990, 1991, 1992, etc through 2011 as defined in your loop?)  If not, this would be an error.  Here, again, you are dynamically providing the name of the column that you expect to exist in the input table.

5 & 6.  You could also receive this error on your `OpenRecordset` commands if the tables, named in your two constants don't exist.

This addresses the issue with your code sample, but does not address whether your approach to transform the data for your other stated purposes is correct or not as we do not have enough additional information.

Comment: I have been playing with the code this morning and testing it to get it going.   I figured out what you mentioned and your right. I was unsure of how the DAO Recordset objects work.  I was able to get the error code for that line of code fixed by referencing the correct field in the source table.  Now I am getting the same type of error on the rstoutput line with the [data type].  Do I have to completely build my output table with the fields in place before running this code?  Up to this point I assumed that it would automatically populate the fields from the original table records.

Comment: Yes, all of the columns that you want in the output table must already exist.  You cannot dynamically create and/or modify the design of a table using recordset objects.  So, yes, your table must be fully defined before running this code.

Comment: So I need to take every record from the old table and build a column for each one in the destination table before it is recognized by the object?

Comment: If you need a column in your output table for every possible value from the [Data Type] column from your input table, then yes, you need to create those columns in the output table, assuming you keep the code the way you have it in your question.